# How to add ordered pairs as both key and value in a map in java?

Tags: java

Let's say I have the following input

3
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6

Where the first number is the number of inputs (3 in this case) and the next few lines represents a pair of coordinate pairs (ex. (1,2),(3,4))

I would like to store this data in a Tree Map as such

map = {(1,2),(3,4);(2,3),(3,5);(3,4),(5,6)}

So far I tried initializing the map like this

```
TreeMap <TreeMap <Integer,Integer>, TreeMap <Integer,Integer>> map = new TreeMap<>();
```

But I am not sure how I can store the data (maybe using the put method) in the map.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use a TreeMap for this, what value does it have over an ArrayList? If you really want to add data to the TreeMap then yes use a loop to iterate through the input and put each pair into the TreeMap `yourMap.put(key, value);`

Comment: why not write a coordinate class to hold two values and add these values into your map as key and value? much simpler than nesting the maps.

Comment: I don't understand what the key is?  It looks like you have a List<Coordinate> to me.  You can use the java.awt.Point class to hold a coordinate.